# IllegalArgumentException ,where's the error in my code?

Tags: java

Hmm I can't find the error:

```
package udemy;

public class ClassOne {

private int positiveNum;

public ClassOne (int positiveNum){


    if (positiveNum< 0 ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("positiveNum should be greater than 0");
    }

    this.positiveNum= positiveNum;
}

public int getNum(){
    return positiveNum;
}

}
```

And in my main class, i got this code:

```
package udemy;

public class ClassTwo {
public static void main (String[] args) {


    ClassOne number= new ClassOne(-15);
    try {
        System.out.printf("%s%n",number.getNum());
    } 
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) 
    {
        System.out.printf("%s",e.getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

But i get following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:positiveNum should be greater than 0
 at udemy.ClassOne.<init>(ClassOne.java:11)
at udemy.ClassTwo.main(ClassTwo.java:7)
```

Instead of saying that number should be greater than 0.
Where the error?

Answer (score 5):

It is saying that it should be greater than 0.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:**positiveNum should be greater than 0** at udemy.ClassOne.(ClassOne.java:11) at udemy.ClassTwo.main(ClassTwo.java:7)

But the true issue is that you should be creating the value in the try block, like this:

```
package udemy;

public class ClassTwo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            ClassOne number= new ClassOne(-15);
            System.out.printf("%s%n",budala.getNum());
        } 
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) 
        {
            System.out.printf("%s",e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue. The standard display of an uncaught exception is:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:positiveNum should be greater than 0 at udemy.ClassOne.(ClassOne.java:11) at udemy.ClassTwo.main(ClassTwo.java:7)
> ```

or

```
Exception in thread "threadName" ExceptionType:message 
at StackTraceElement
at StackTraceElement
...
```

If you want to have a different appearance to this, you must catch the exception *within the try block*.

```
    //...
    try {
        ClassOne number= new ClassOne(-15);
        System.out.printf("%s%n",budala.getNum());
    } 
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) 
    {
        System.out.printf("%s",e.getMessage());
    }
    // ...
```